# salt stack `os:...` pattern not matching in top.sls

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, arch-linux, saltstack

I'm attempting to differentiate between a Ubuntu box and an Arch box within my `top.sls` file within a `Virtualbox 5.0.4` virtual machine managed by `vagrant 1.7.4` using `salt 2015.8.1 (Beryllium)`

This doesn't work:

```
base:
    'os:Arch':
        - base.arch
```

This *does* work:

```
base:
    {% if grains['os'] == 'Arch' %}
    '*':
        - base.arch
    {% endif %}
```

Excerpt from `salt-call grains.items`:

```
os:
    Arch
os_family:
    Arch
osarch:
    x86_64
oscodename:
osfullname:
    Arch Linux
osrelease:
```

Does anyone have any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
base:
  'os:Arch':
    - match: grain
    - base.arch
```

See https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/top.html

Comment: ah, I *completely* overlooked that next line. I did think it must be doing some pretty clever pattern matching without hinting.